# Не открывает сайт с fastpanel

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, site, firewall

Утсановил fastpanel на vps сервер который работает на ОС ubuntu 20. После установки, я увидел сайт, посетил его и мне выдало ошибку что время ожидания истекло, хотя я делал sudo ufw allow 8888. Нигде не нашёл ответа, поэтому очень нуждаюсь в вашей помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что дело в firewall, скорее всего что-либо другое. Вы можете обратиться по адресу https://cp.fastpanel.direct и попросить помощи у саппорта, помощь бесплатная.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос